# How do you execute an arbitrary string inside a powershell script/function as though the string had actually been typed into the script/function?

Tags: variables, powershell, pipeline

I can't get my function to work using iex (invoke-expression) with variables. What I want:

```
function My-Function {

    # code that constructs $command 
    #$command is an arbitrary string that may contain pipes, 
    #variables, command line paramaters, switchs, quoted strings, THE LOT!

    Execute-My-Command-Exactly-As-Though-I-Had-Typed-It-Here $command
}
```

For example

```
function My-Function {
    $command = "`$input | select-string hello"

    iex $command
}
```

Does this (after . including my file which contains the above function)

```
PS C:\> echo "hello" | My-Function
PS C:\>
```

But obviously it should do this:

```
PS C:\> echo "hello" | My-Function

hello


PS C:\>
```

Moreover on the actual command line, variables DO seem to be picked up by iex:

```
PS C:\> $hello = "hello"
PS C:\>
PS C:\> iex "`$hello | select-string hello"

hello


PS C:\>
```

The only workaround I can think of is to actually write out a function to a file, then . include it, then call it.  But this is awful! The whole point of a good shell-scripting language is it should be able to do this meta stuff easy peasy.

SOLUTION:

PowerShell can't do it, though latkin provides a helpful tip.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?  Why?  With a little more understanding of the high-level problem you're trying to solve, we may be able to point the way to a more PowerShell-y answer. :)

Comment: In bash if $command holds a line of a script / command line, we can call it with the line "$command", of course in WeakShell that would just output $command as text. What I want is Execute-My-Command-Exactly-As-Though-I-Had-Typed-It-Here :P

Comment: @samthebest: call another command in powershell with the call operator: & $command -- call a bunch of commands with a scriptblock (lambda / anonymous function):  &  { cmd1; cmd2 }

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to run before you can walk. That said, let's take a look at your first example above:

```
function my-function {
    process {
       $_ | select-string "hello"
    }    
}

"hello" | my-function
```

Now, you may be saying to yourself: "Hey, that's not what I asked!" and to this, I offer the following advice on Invoke-Expression (iex): Executing arbitrary text like this can be dangerous, and is rarely required. It generally indicates a lack of understanding of building interoperable functions and modules. Even throwaway scripts rarely require IEX.

So, I'm not just going to leave it there but I can't reasonably answer your question without a higher level point of view on what you're trying to do. It sounds like you're trying to generalize some process for executing script, or scripts. So, my advice would be to study the various native mechanisms for doing this in PowerShell, namely the dot source (.) and call (&) operators.

And finally, grab a coffee and sit back to read through Keith Hill's most excellent "Effective Windows PowerShell" free ebook:

http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/effective-windows-powershell-the-free-ebook/

The first few chapters will help you to *help yourself* when learning the right way to do things. It covers the primary tools of PowerShell: get-command, get-help, get-member and understanding the difference between *command* and *expression* modes.

Comment: Thanks for the book, and yes commands like man and gm are very useful (obviously not half as useful as to their bash equivalents :P ).

Your dislike of executing arbitrary text generally indicates a lack of understanding of the power of meta-scripting. The more expressive a language the more we can abstract out structure, which leads to totally DRY code, which is in fact safer and easier to debug.

Comment: If you think bash has an equivalent to get-member (gm) then it's you, dear sir, who is completely lost. This is what differentiates an object-based pipeline from a text-processing one like bash. Think of powershell as being bash with automagic awk/sed. Windows configuration is API based; Unix is text file based. Different tools, different platforms, different approaches. You'll get used to it eventually.

Comment: The man pages, and common flags -u (usage), -h (help), -i (non-interactive), -s (scripting mode), used together with common bash commands are the equivalent.  In bash the automagic happens in the command line flags, good knowledge of bash commands means sed generally need only be used to process actual text.  Think of bash as being powershell with automagic typing, and thus no need for a rigid restrictive OOP pipeline.  Seeing bash as text based is like looking at the raw data on the PS pipeline - then getting rather confused. You'll get used to it eventually ;)

Comment: lol... I applaud your creativity. I am an old unix hack myself, so your jedi mind tricks won't work on me ;-) My first kernel was linux 1.2.3.

Answer (score 0):

`$input` is [a very weird special case automatic variable](http://dmitrysotnikov.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/input-gotchas/).  It is a bad idea to rely on it at all, let alone in combination with `Invoke-Expression`.  I'm guessing `$input` is only in scope in the function body itself, and vanishes in the scope of the expression you are invoking dynamically.

I echo @x0n's sentiments completely.  This sounds like some really hacky, fragile, hard to debug, hard to maintain stuff.  Think over your goals, and figure out some **standard** functions and variables which encapsulate the problem space.  Read up on function parameters, piped parameters, etc, so you can take advantage of the best proper solution, which has proper support from the language.

That being said...  You can kind of work around this by creating a scriptblock, which allows for arguments to be passed from the outside.

```
function My-Function{
    & ([scriptblock]::Create('param($newInput); "Newinput is $newInput"')) $input
}

'piped1', 'piped2' |  my-function
```

Comment: True, that. However, I foresee his next pain point with not realising that the single quotes are required to prevent variable expansion of the parameter $newInput. Even the simple examples are not so simple for an absolute newbie.

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful, nearly what I wanted, and I think as close as WeakShell will allow.  It will be a pain declaring and passing in variables, but I can easily get a pre-processor to do that. Yes it seems VerboseShell's scoping rules are one of it's pitfalls.

Comment: Um... "weakshell?" "verboseshell?" I see you're trying really hard to defend your inability or unwillingness to actually learn something new. Good job. Instead of moaning how Windows != Unix or PS != bash, pay attention in class. You'll be a better man for it.

Comment: Ad hominem. I'm just jovially saying it's weak and verbose because I believe it to be true! This thread provides one of 1000s of examples of something PS simply can't do, but bash can.  Instead of trying to read my mind and pick arguments, pay attention in class. You'll be a better man for it.

Comment: You think powershell is more verbose than bash? Now I've heard everything.